# Exciting vs Inciting

Tags: grammar, word-usage, legalese

The Indian Penal Code made in 1860 by the British  made sedition an offence. Sedition was defined as exciting disaffection towards the Government.
The old law is being replaced by a new one which deletes 'sedition' from the statute book because of criticism that it sought to suppress free speech. The new enactment includes a new provision which declares that 'exciting secession , armed rebellion or subversive activities' is an offence.

1. Is the use of the word 'exciting' appropriate in this context? Can secession be excited? A wag asks, 'To what extent must secession be excited to be deemed an offence?' Would 'inciting' be the correct term?
2. And for that matter, is it correct usage to talk about 'exciting disaffection'?

Answer (score 2):

A definition of *excite* is given in [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/excite):

> a : to call to activity
>
> b: to rouse to an emotional response
>
> c: to arouse (something, such as a strong emotional response) by appropriate stimuli

In this sense, *excite* and *incite* [are synonyms](https://www.merriam-webster.com/thesaurus/incite). They both come from the same Latin word meaning ["arouse, urge"](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/excite#Etymology)